# Find altitude of equilateral triangle given inscribed circle dimensions and position

Tags: circles, triangles

I've found myself trying to solve this for my Geometry class where we have to model a basic piece of architecture and find its volume and surface area (very basic). But the structure I chose requires me to find its dimensions via some other given dimensions. I've made a diagram linked below. So what is the altitude (and how did you find it, if possible?)

[image: Equilateral triangle with inscribed circle placed in one corner]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The altitude of your triangle is 24. You can conclude this by analytic geometry. Let's work with the xy-plane. Suppose that the $x$-axis contains the bottom side of your triangle and that the $y$-axis contains your red vertical segment. If the line $L$ that contains the right side of the triangle has equation  $y=mx+c$, then $c$ is the altitude of the triangle.

Lets denote by $D$ the red diagonal (segment) of length 6 of your diagram. Choose $D$ such that it's perpendicular to the right side of the triangle. Since the angle between the $y$-axis and $D$ is 60,  the line that contains $D$ has equation $y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}x+12$. Using this equation we can deduce that $m=-\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}$ and that the intersection of $D$ and the right side of the triangle is the point $(3\sqrt{3},15)$. Since this point is part of $L$ we conclude that $L$ has equation $y=-\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}x+24$. Hence $c=24$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. I can't express how much this has helped me.